# I admire, in China, that they want to do this seriously

Tags: word-usage

This is why even a small 50-qubit quantum computer can beat a massive classical supercomputer. “If you look at the West—the U.S., Europe—there haven’t been a lot of people talking about repeating [Google’s 2019] experiment,” Martinis says. “**I admire, in China, that they want to do this seriously**.”
Source: Scientific American
China Is Pulling Ahead in Global Quantum Race, New Studies Suggest

I don't understand the meaning of "in" in the phrase "I admire, in China, that they want to do this seriously."  When using "admire" to show respect or approval, we usually use "admire the object (e.g., the object is "your courage" or "the scientist") and there is no "in".) Now "admire in China"? What does it mean? Does it mean "admire China"? Does it mean "admire (the courage/wisdom showed **in** the effort by) China"? Or the use of "in" is simply a mistake? I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted sentence is a conversational way of saying, "*I admire **that** in China they want to do this seriously.* This is certainly an unprepared quote -- someone speaking "off-the-cuff". If Martinis had written it or even had a moment to think about it, they would have phrased it similar to the way I did.